# Any Storage format developed or development in progress by Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am currently working on batch applications using Apache Spark and we are using the storage format mainly as delimiter separated text file and parquet.

Is there any storage format developed by spark or are there any plans to develop any storage format?

Comment: Spark does not have own storage format. Have a look at alternatives at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669187/is-hdfs-necessary-for-spark-workloads/34789554#34789554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark is highly agnostic when it comes to languages, cluster managers and supported data sources, including file formats and file systems. Moreover it is a general purpose framework so finding a solution which fits all scenarios is rather unlikely.

That being seeing said it is always worth to watch [AMPLab projects page](https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/projects).